# Multiple Paragraph Styles Within One Line

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I am creating a document to log updates that have been done to a piece of software. It's a regular table with columns for version and an abbreviated changelog.

For this changelog column, I am using four distinct descriptions, e.g. "Security" or "Bugfix".

To improve readability, I want to assign a different style to each element so that each item has it's own color code. While I successfully created the paragraph styles I want, I don't know how to apply different styles within one line of the table.

For now, it looks like this:

[image: Current style]

The first and last cells are just as I want them to look, but for cells with multiple elements, like the second line in the picture above, I want to apply different styles for each element, ideally with a spacer in between so that there are multiple, separated bubbles for each element.

I hope I could point out my issue well enough and am hoping for helpful responses.

Comment: Hi David Ramiro, and welcome to GDSE,  we need more information to find an answer, the colored background of each element belongs to the paragraph style or they are anchored objects?

Comment: Hello Danielillo, the background belongs to a paragraph style, it's basically done via paragraph shading. I have also tried to to do this via character style but there is no option to do shading like this.

Comment: I think changing different sentences background color at the same paragraph is quite impossible. Maybe a trick with next styles, or different linked anchor objects, or dividing the cell in columns.

Comment: The best I can come up with is to use one paragraph style and inside that define Grep styles to match specific words. Something like: "If the text is `'Improvement'` use character style `type-Improvement` and if the text is `'Bugfix'` use character style `type-bugfix`" etc. You can't get the rounded corners this way, but it would be very simple and easy to control. — The only other solution I could come up with is to wrap each word into their own rectangle frames and give those their own object styles. That would be more involved, but you could keep the rounded corners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use `Paragraph Styles` to alter type within the same paragraph. As the name indicates, `Paragraph Styles` apply to entire paragraphs.

You **can** use `Character Styles` to create formatting presets for text within the same paragraph. You can have as many `Character Styles` inside a paragraph as you want.

[image]

You can use the **Underline** options in Character styles to create the background. However, the rounded corners may be impossible via underlines.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked flawlessly. I played around with Character Styles before aswell as mentioned in another comment but gave up due to the lack of Shading options. I never thought of using Underline as a background. Even without rounded corners, this looks exactly like I want it to.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I shouldn't have used paragraph style to design the dictionary. It took a lot of time, word by word making the first word bold and the rest regular. Character style is the answer. Thank you, I appreciate your help